# Search only document libraries using KeywordQuery

Tags: search, keywordquery

Is it possible using KeywordQuery to pull back all (only) records that are documents in document libraries? Wondering if there is a KeywordQuery.QueryText property I can use for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `IsDocument:1` to show only results that are documents.